# Is there any way to set default date range in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there any way in elasticsearch to set a default date range if to and from fields are null. Like whenever to and from are empty, then elasticsearch should perform search on the basis of defined default range. I have written a query but it only works in the case if to and from is defined:

```
"range": {
            "time": {
              "from": "2018-01-16T07:05:00",
              "to": "2018-01-16T10:59:09",
              "include_lower": true,
              "include_upper": true
            }
          }
```

Comment: can you post your query along with your question.

Answer (score 0):

There is no default date range in elasticsearch right now.

If you didn't provide any date range filter, the elasticsearch will search the entire records which match your query.

It will search the entire index or alias you have pointed to search.

My suggestion would be

If you want to set a default time frame in your filter, you have to do that in your code  (means client side).
So your program should set a time frame example - Last 30 days or something.